# How to config Oracle Data Integrator to restart when a job is error?

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

My company is using Oracle Data Integrator for ETL jobs. Recently, there's an issue with a source database that lead to extracting job sometimes fail (very randomly, once or twice per 10 extract jobs). When we restart the job, most of the times it run successfully.

So while we are trying to fix the connection to source database, is there any way to restart that particular job 1 or 2 times if it fails? How can I config that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enclose the scenario in a package. Then, set the *Processing after failure* options in the package *Advanced* tab:

[image: ODI Screenshot]